# Why does Java allow null value to be assigned to an Enum?

Tags: java, enums

This is more of a design question, so no code. I could post code of creating an Enum and assigning it to `null` if you want me to do it. :))

I've been thinking a lot about this lately, but can't come up with one good reason. The Enum constants are implicitly *static* and *final*. Enum is meant to say - "I can take a value of one of the constants present in me". Why allow Enum to have a `null` value? Why not implicitly default the Enum's value to a `Enum.DEFAULT` or `Enum.None`? Isn't this a better approach than allowing the Enum to be `null`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Firstly `null` means non-existence of an instance. Providing a default constant like `DEFAULT` or `NONE`, will change that meaning. Secondly, why would you need something default to represent what seems to be non-existent? That is the purpose of `null`. Basically, you would have to initialize and store an extra object, which shouldn't even exist whatsoever.

BTW, it's not a language choice. It's completely on you how you implement your enum. You can provide another constant like `DEFAULT`, or `UNKNOWN` in your enum, and avoid the assignment of `null` to the reference in your code. This is famously known as [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). But saying that the `null` assignment should itself be compiler error, then I would say, since an `Enum` is anyways compiled to a `Class`, so it would be perfectly valid to use `null` to represent non-existence of an instance.

One pitfall of allowing `null` though is with the usage of `enum` in `switch-case`. The below code will throw `NPE`, even with a `default` case:

```
public class Demo {
    enum Color {
        WHITE, BLACK;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Color color = null;

        switch (color) {    // NPE here
        case WHITE: break;
        case BLACK: break;
        default: break;     // null value does not fall into the default
        }
    }
}
```

Java does not allow a `case null:` either, producing the following compile error:

> an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant

Comment: On the contarary, what sense would it make to point an Enum to null when Enum is supposed to take a value within itself?. Oracle doc - An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. The variable must be equal to one of the values that have been predefined for it.

Comment: I think you simply need to validate your data, because e.g when the data comes from outside your system, you are not guaranteed the guy, who sends the request, knows what consequences of using the default value are.

Comment: @Andrei it is not a default value, but a null value represented by a value. Just like empty collections for instance. Null object pattern used on Enums.

Comment: @AndreiI - Exactly. If a guy send me null instead of an expected Enum constant, it should throw a Runtime Exception saying - "you are supposed to send an Enum constant". By allowing null, it breaks the design which says - "I know what values I can get." ( of course i can compare the calue with null. but I don't like doing it)

Comment: @rohit - I still think Enum should not be assigned to null. :). I think  Color color = null; // should give compile time error ( or runtime if I get it dynamically.)

Comment: @rohit It is absolutely a language choice.  A pitiful one, which your answer in no way justifies.

Comment: I disagree with the explanation and logic of this answer.

Comment: _"Firstly null means non-existence of an instance. Providing a default constant like DEFAULT or NONE, will change that meaning."_  Not in the least.  The ruleset for enums _might very sensibly have been_ an enforced non-null contract.  Leaving the only choices to be either 1. something akin to `Enum.DEFAULT`, etc., when unspecified, or **2. disallowing unspecified declarations at all.**  The goal of enums should have been specifically to rigidly define a domain of literals.  Not have a domain of literals along with an clumsy monkywrench thrown in that you have to check for.

Answer (score 7):

Java allows any reference to be null, and references to enums aren't so special that a special case needs to be made to prevent it, or to provide another version of behaviour that is already well-specified and well-understood. Null is already a perfectly adequate sentinel value: we don't need another one.

Neither of your suggestions is convincing, as they would both require addition of yet further features to support them.

In any case it is several years too late to start debating the point.

Comment: My suggestions might be incorrect.yet, its never too late .. example - switching based on Strings :P

Comment: Of course it's too late. Nobody is going to introduce language changes that aren't backwards-compatible.

Comment: Well enums are special enough that they have their own keyword so it's one more step to allow the compiler to treat them special and barf on setting one to null (I agree with OP). The omission appears an arbitrary design choice to me. It's orthogonal whether or not this will make it into the language.

Comment: @scorpiodawg Electing to preserve backwards compatibility is hardly 'arbitrary'.

Answer (score 4):

I think, `Enum.DEFAULT` means that your enum variable contains a value, but `null` doesn't. If it's `null` it can be interpreted that it has no value, you can't invoke non-static methods on it for example.

Comment: On the contarary, what sense would it make to point an Enum to null when Enum is supposed to take a value within itself?. Oracle doc - An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. The variable must be equal to one of the values that have been predefined for it.

Comment: @WhoAmI, because enum variable is a reference to object and it can point to nothing (=empty variable) or to one of enum's values.

Answer (score 2):

You can add behaviour to your enums (Domain Driven Design), for instance add a public method named prettyPrint() that returns a String based on your enum value. How a default / null value can provide an implementation of this custom method?

If you want to represent null with an enum, then you'll have to explicit this by using a null object pattern manually with a NONE value and a custom implementation for prettyPrint() based on NONE value.

Answer (score 0):

Old, I know. I'm half-in Java.

> Why allow Enum to have a null value?

There are few use cases, I believe. For example, we need to initialize an enum variable to tell us it's not really part of the enum, but we can change its value later, so that it is part of it. If there was no way to initialize an enum variable as `null`, then we would pollute the enum definition. So, in my opinion, fields such as `LibEnum.NONE` messes libraries. For example, you don't want one to use `LibEnum.NONE` as parameters for methods, between others.

I found it useful in my lexical scanner, among with keywords and punctuators. Suppose you've an identifier `"blah"`. You then want to check if it's any keyword.

```
private Keywordv getKeywordValue(String id)
{
    switch (id.length())
    {
        case 2:
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case "do": return Keywordv.DO;
                case "if": return Keywordv.IF;
                case "is": return Keywordv.IS;

                // ...
            }

            break;
        }

        // ...
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thanks to `null`, it's then easy to verify whether the identifier is not a keyword.

```
id == null
```

Otherwise we'd have to define something like `Keywordv.__NULL`